# Why are FSTN graphic LCDs not made in resolutions higher than 320x240?

Tags: lcd, glcd

I am interested in designing and building a low-power Raspberry Pi-based palmtop computer to use a (FS)TN monochrome transflective LED-backlit LCD, like that in the [HP 300LX](https://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&id=172&c=hewlett-packard_palmtop_300lx) or the [Psion Series 5](https://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&id=12607&c=psion_series_5_8mb_special_edition). Those devices use a 640x240 (HVGA) resolution. I have found a ton of graphic LCDs up to a resolution of 320x240 (QVGA), including the following:

- https://www.andersdx.com/display-products/?48%5B%5D=FSTN
- https://www.phoenixdisplay.com/product/monochrome-displays/graphic-display/
- https://www.raystar-optronics.com/products.php?func=p_list&sub=filter&lang=eng&pc_parent=253&pc_id_str=11%2C30%2C39%2C48%2C57%2C66%2C75%2C210%2C129%2C111%2C138%2C84%2C400%2C436%2C401%2C228%2C442%2C430%2C336%2C403&pst_id_11_3=%23&pst_id_30=320%C3%97240&pst_id_39=%23&pst_id_48=%23&pst_id_57=%23&pst_id_66=%23&pst_id_75=%23&pst_id_129=%23&pst_id_111_3=%23&pst_id_84=%23&pst_id_400=%23#content

Even the [memory LCDs](https://www.sharpmemorylcd.com/4-4-inch-memory-lcd.html) stop at 340x240.

However, it is extremely difficult - I have had no success - finding FSTN graphic LCDs  at resolutions higher than 320x240. Why is this so? And are there leads to find an  (FS)TN monochrome transflective LED-backlit LCD at a resolution more like 640x240?

I know I could repurpose a display from a late-90s palmtop for my project, create a custom LCD, or use e-ink, but I am curious why the resolution of FSTN graphic LCDs available for purchase nowadays seems to stop at 320x240.

Comment: Market reasons are why transflective screens are rare in general. I nabbed big one one for a project a 10 years ago after 10 years of searching. Should have grabbed two or three since they became unavailable very quickly.

Comment: If you're willing to order enough they'll probably make whatever resolution you want, but for off the shelf parts there isn't a lot of demand for high resolution transreflective displays anymore.